# How do I make the navigation bar/header sticky on zendesk help centre?

Tags: html, css, header, sticky

I want to edit the code base on my zendesk help centre to make the top navigation bar/header sticky.

This is the original header code in zendesk that I want to edit:

```
<a class="skip-navigation" tabindex="1" href="#main-content">{{t 'skip_navigation' }}</a>

<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    {{#link 'help_center'}}
      <img src="{{settings.logo}}" alt="{{t 'home_page' name=help_center.name}}" />
      {{#if settings.show_brand_name}}
        <span aria-hidden="true">{{help_center.name}}</span>
      {{/if}}
    {{/link}}
  </div>

  <div class="nav-wrapper-desktop">
    <nav class="user-nav" id="user-nav">
      <ul class="user-nav-list">
        <li>{{link 'community'}}</li>
        {{#unless signed_in}}
          <li>
            {{#link "sign_in" class="sign-in"}}
              {{t 'sign_in'}}
            {{/link}}
          </li>
        {{/unless}}
      </ul>
    </nav>
    {{#if signed_in}}
      <div class="user-info dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">
          {{user_avatar class="user-avatar"}}
          <span>
            {{user_name}}
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="12" height="12" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 12 12" class="dropdown-chevron-icon" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" d="M3 4.5l2.6 2.6c.2.2.5.2.7 0L9 4.5"/>
            </svg>
          </span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          {{#my_profile role="menuitem"}}{{t 'profile'}}{{/my_profile}}
          {{link "requests" role="menuitem"}}
          {{#link "contributions" role="menuitem"}}{{t "activities"}}{{/link}}
          {{contact_details role="menuitem"}}
          {{change_password role="menuitem"}}
          <div class="separator" role="separator"></div>
          {{link "sign_out" role="menuitem"}}
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/if}}
  </div>

  <div class="nav-wrapper-mobile">
    <button class="menu-button-mobile" aria-controls="user-nav-mobile" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{t 'toggle_navigation'}}">
      {{#if signed_in}}
        {{user_avatar class="user-avatar"}}
      {{/if}}
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="icon-menu">
        <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" d="M1.5 3.5h13m-13 4h13m-13 4h13"/>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <nav class="menu-list-mobile" id="user-nav-mobile" aria-expanded="false">
      <ul class="menu-list-mobile-items">
        {{#if signed_in}}
          <li class="user-avatar-item item">
            {{#my_profile role="menuitem" class="my-profile"}}
              {{user_avatar class="menu-profile-avatar"}}
              <div class="menu-profile-name">
                <div>{{user_name}}</div>
                <div class="my-profile-tooltip">{{t 'profile'}}</div>
              </div>
            {{/my_profile}}
          </li>
          <li class="item">{{link "requests" role="menuitem"}}</li>
          <li class="item">{{#link "contributions" role="menuitem"}}{{t "activities"}}{{/link}}</li>
          <li class="item">{{contact_details role="menuitem"}}</li>
          <li class="item">{{change_password role="menuitem" class='change-password'}}</li>
          <li class="nav-divider"></li>
        {{else}}
          <li class="item">
            {{#link "sign_in" role="menuitem"}}
              {{t 'sign_in'}}
            {{/link}}
          </li>
          <li class="nav-divider"></li>
        {{/if}}
        <li class="item">{{link 'community' role="menuitem"}}</li>
        <li class="item">{{link 'new_request' role="menuitem" class='submit-a-request'}}</li>
        <li class="nav-divider"></li>
        {{#if signed_in}}
          <li class="item">
            {{link "sign_out" role="menuitem"}}
          </li>
        {{/if}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</header>
```

Has anyone edited Zendesk help centre code before that could help me?

I tried adding:

```
 <style>
  .header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Adjust this to match your desired background color */
    /* Add any other styles you want for the sticky navigation bar */
  }
</style>
```

Which worked but the edges/sides of the header are not sticky. I need to nav bar to reach to the edge of the screen.